# Is it possible to make a div that is not rounded or square shaped with html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have received a design which i am pretty sure is a flash website yet the company is convinced that it is doable in html, [the design](http://tinypic.com/r/zwmibl/6)
Any feedback would be nice.

Comment: What kind of browser-support do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable indeed, but if you intend to support older browsers, like IE8, you will have to make use of transparent PNG-images that you use as backgrounds on the elements, in order to create the tilted effect on the elements.

If you don't need to support older browsers, you can have a look att [CSS3 transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform).

Comment: How should i proceed in doing it ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa One way would be to save the white and blue tilted boxes as images (transparent PNGS, so the background will be able to shine through where the boxes are skewed, then use the images as backgrounds in the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this:

```
   #parallelogram {
      width: 130px; 
      height: 75px;
      background: pink;
      /* Skew */
      -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
      -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
      -o-transform: skew(20deg);
      transform: skew(20deg);
   }
```

==edit==

Ok, so unskew the text part:

```
<div style="width: 130px; 
      height: 75px;
      background: pink;
      /* Skew */
      -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
      -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
      -o-transform: skew(20deg);
      transform: skew(20deg);">
    <div style=" margin:2em;
      -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg); 
      -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
      -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
      transform: skew(-20deg);
    ">inner text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: skewing distorts the text in it

Answer (score 0):

make images for those backgrounds, and make them background images of the divs on which you wish to present content.

Comment: agreed..just a quick fix if it's the last option...personally though, I like @end-user 's response!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vYU7N/2/

It's using different sized borders to create the diagonals.

```
#left{
  position:absolute;
  border-right:200px solid #0080bf;
  border-top:500px solid transparent;
  left:-200px;
  top:0;
}

#right{
  position:absolute;
  border-left:200px solid #0080bf;
  border-bottom:500px solid transparent;
  right:-200px;
  top:0;
}

#container{
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:460px;
  margin-left:250px;
  background:#0080bf;
  padding:20px;
  color: white;
}
```

It takes a little bit of adjustment.  Tested and works in Chrome/IE8

Comment: nice :D but there's a risk for it not to "stick" since every browser interprets css slightly differently

Comment: Actually, this is pretty stick-proof.  I've since checked out Firefox and IE7.  The only thing strange that happens is with padding in IE7.  And really nobody should ever use that browser :).  The main problem I see with my method is that you can't actually put content into the #left and #right areas since they are just borders.  Google uses this same technique with its music service, as explained by this guy: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use http://raphaeljs.com/ very versatile and shouldn't add too much 'weight' to your site

Answer (score -1):

You can use "clip-path" to shape special elements.
See more: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/